# Mongoose.js: fill of additional field for a model instance

Tags: mongoose

Say I have a schema

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: 'string',
    password: 'string,
    age: {type: 'number', select: false}

})

User.find({...}).exec().then(function(user){

  //user.age -> is undefined
  ...
  // LATER I want "age" to be filled from DB

  //So I may do (I may also wrap in custom model method)
  User.findById(user._id, 'age').exec().then(function(userOnlyAge){
     user.age = userOnlyAge.age
     ..
  })

})
```

What is the best way to fill it better way? I wonder if it is possible out of the box?

Comment: what exactly is your problem? Do you need to update the age?

Comment: So I may restrict number of fields selected from db while "initial" select, so I want to fill (get value) of some field FROM database LATER, for particular model instance.